# Distribution chart not showing bars in AnyLogic

Tags: histogram, anylogic

So I've set up a simulation to measure the time it would take for a ship to get from houston to sydney. I put a time measure start and end between the move to block and made a distribution chart using a histogram. But when I run the simulation, the bars don't show up. The numbers are still there, and the rest of the histograms are working properly, but no bars on this particular one.[Here is a screenshot of the simulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJBbF.png), histogram in question is the second one.

@Emile Zankoul
[image: Here is the properties of the moveTo block in question]

Answer (score 0):

Can't be 100% sure why.
Try to copy and paste one of the two histograms that work then change the time measure name in the new histogram's properties.

I think most likely, you have "Show PDF" unchecked:
[image]

Make sure it is checked.

---

After reviewing the model I realized that the total measured duration is over 1,000,000 seconds. It seems there is a limitation to the maximum value for the histogram. So to resolve this, change your model time units from seconds to anything bigger (e.g. minutes, hours, etc.).

Comment: I have show PDF selected and its still not showing. Though when I make the chart into a dataset ,I see that it plots out a straight line which is weird. Both locations are GIS regions which means there should be some variation in time for every iteration, yet it is constant.

Comment: Hmm, then it seems related to how you define your "moveTo" element. Can you send a pic of the properties of your related "moveTo" block?

Comment: Sure thing. I've added it to my posted question.

Comment: I'm sorry, couldn't figure out an answer with the given information...
Feel free to share the model if you'd like me to look more into it.

Comment: No worries, any help would be appreciated. Let me know if you can find the problem. Here's a link the simulation file: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ZGczivxjDJ1hfBzP_LUYDGZoiPEH8fHG?usp=sharing

Comment: Your link is not public... I requested access though still didn't get it.

Comment: Sorry about that, just changed the permission settings, try again. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1BXtx5_eDiKfFdVNYRqpggR0KXSlYCFMF?usp=sharing

Comment: OK, it appears there is a limitation to histograms which is a maximum of 1,000,000 time units. To resolve it change the time units of your model so that the total duration is less than 1,000,000.

Comment: I revised the answer.

Comment: Aaah I see. It works fine now, thanks for the help!